# If $f$ is entire and $f^{(5)}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 5

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove:

> If $f$ is entire and $f^{(5)}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is
>   a polynomial of degree at most 5.

I think that Liouville's Theorem could be applicable here, however I don't think I can necessarily say $f^{(5)}$ is entire, which would be required to use Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then $f'$ is also holomorphic at $z_0$ since it has a powerseries representation around $z_0$ with the same radius of convergence as $f$.

Answer (score 4):

An entire function is  infinitely differentiable and its derivatives are entire as well. Therefore, your idea is good: just apply Liouville's theorem to the function $f^{(5)}$: you get that $f^{(5)}$ is a constant, hence $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 5. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand intuitively why $f^{(5)}$ being constant implies that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 5, but how would I best prove this?

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, an holomorphic function is equal to its power series. Does this help you?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.