# Entire Function, $n$-th derivative bounded is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function  and $f^{(n)}$ is bounded. Show that $f$ is a polynomial with degree of $n$.

**My Idea:** So in somehow I have to use Liouville's Theorem. So we have to prove that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Apply Liouville to $f^{(n)}$, not to $f$ ...

Comment: First show that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is a constant using Liouville. Then integrate up $n$ times.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791306/if-f-is-entire-and-f5-is-bounded-in-mathbbc-then-f-is-a-polynomi.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Liouville we can write $f^{(n)} (z)= c_n $ is konstant. Then
\begin{align*}
f^{(n-1)} (z) = c_n z + c_{n-1} \Rightarrow f^{(n-2)} = \frac{1}{2} c_n z^{2} + c_{n-1} z + c_{n-2} \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow f^{(0)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k z^{k}}{k!}
\end{align*}